# Margin note and paragraph not aligned when skipping a page

Tags: footnotes, marginnote

I am using the "marginnote" and "geometry" packages to set marginnotes features:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3.2cm, bottom=3cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=2.3cm, marginparsep=0.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\scriptsize\sffamily\bfseries}
```

and I call margin notes just before the paragraph:

```
\marginnote{Unification sociétale.}[0.4cm]Le Monde comme \og{}société\fg{} représente la \og{}combinaison...
```

At the end of a page, if a paragraph is pushed on the next page, margin notes do not follow the paragraph it is connected to. In this picture, I would expect the margin note "Unification sociétale" to be aligned to the paragraph beginning by "Le Monde..." on the next page.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can keep margin note and paragraph knit together?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) I'd use `\marginnote` *after* the first word of the paragraph instead of before (`Le\marginnote{Unification sociétale.}[0.4cm]`). This should solve your issue.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, thanks a lot @cgnieder !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution should be to use `\marginnote` *after* the first word of the paragraph instead of before it:

```
Le\marginnote{Unification sociétale.}[0.4cm] Monde comme ...
```

I am not providing a complete example since the question doesn't provide one either and it turns out to be not as easy as I thought to build one myself.